# How do I tether my android phone mic to my windows computer

Tags: microphone

I do not want to buy a standalone mic to be used on my Windows computer. Can I use the mic in my android phone as the mic for my Windows computer?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would probably be [WO Mic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wo.voice&hl=de).